# difference of sum() function in python list and python dataframe/series

Tags: python

I am calculating a column in a dataset "snowfall" of a place in 2016 and 2018. The language is python. I use:

```
snow16=df16['Snowfall'].sum( )
```

this one gets the correct number

```
snow16= sum(df16['Snowfall'])
```

this one gets an incorrect number

I was wondering what's the difference of these two `sum()` functions? Why do they have different results?

Comment: use .sum() for pandas dataframe.

Comment: I know. I just realized this. but the second one "snow16=sum (df['Snowfall'])" can get a number too, I wonder how it gets that number? and why this function isn't correct? In logic, it looks fine.